# ASP.NET Core Authorize by URL

Tags: url, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, authorization, fallback

I am using ASP.NET Core and have a bunch of controllers each with a number of methods. I also have a login controller/method that uses SignInAsync to create a cookie (not using Identity) with claims. The authorization on the controllers uses [Authorize] and a custom built authorization filter that can reject authorisation if a query token causes a mismatch. There are other authorization filters that can reject authorization, e.g. based on IP. This works great.

Now my problem:

I have one controller/method that requires the above authorisation framework, but also allows to be called if the query part contains a certain keyword, e.g. &foo=bar, regardless of a cookie being present or not, i.e. one or more of my authorize filters can have failed.

My problem is that my existing authorize attributes (Authorize and my custom attributes) all can reject the authorization, but if they reject authorization, I need to be able to have my controller be called if the query part matches. How do I do that?

For now, I have implemented the checks into the action method, duplicating the checks:

```
    public async Task<IActionResult> getDoc(Int16 lang, string foo)
    {
        bool allowed = false;
        // normal authentication (is authenticated and check matches claim Id)
        if (HttpContext.User.Identities.Any(i => i.IsAuthenticated))
        {
            if (HttpContext.Request.Query.ContainsKey("verify"))
            {
                var claimId =
                    HttpContext.User.Claims.Where(claim => claim.Type == "VerifyId")
                        .Select(id => id.Value)
                        .FirstOrDefault();
                if (claimId == HttpContext.Request.Query["verify"])
                {
                    // success 
                    allowed = true;
                }
            }
        }
        if (!allowed)
        {
            if (foo == "bar" || foo == "bop")
            {
                allowed = true;
            }
        }
        if (allowed)
        {
            // actual action work here
        }
    }
```

The first `if` matches the `[Authorize, ValidateVerifyId]` attributes all controller actions have (inherited via an otherwise empty default controller). The second `if` performs the query "authorisation" for this action. I haven't found any way through the authorisation system (attributes, handlers, policies) the was flexible enough to help me move this code outside the action. Is it possible?

Comment: I have had a look at the AuthorizationHandler, but it has no HttpContext and as such, the query isn't available for inspection.

Comment: HttpContext was available (via context.Resources), but having just one controller action run with either one authorisation or another seems next to impossible.